# Create private Facebook app to link Chatterbot to sent chats to people

Tags: python, facebook, chat

I have written a Python script to send and fetch Chatterbot chat messages. I now want to create a Facebook app that only I can access that has permission to send chat messages to people, and I want my script to send the messages to Facebook to people, and then back. The end aim to to say hi to everyone, then see how they react. How would I do this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/ is a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

For a list of known Facebook chatbots, see my Meta Guide webpage, "Best Facebook Chatbots" [1].  The Facebook Chat API is XMPP compatible [2].  Google App Engine is also XMPP compatible [3]; so, you should be able to use Python on AppEngine to work with Facebook Chat XMPP.

[1] http://www.meta-guide.com/home/ai-engine/best-facebook-chatbots

[2] http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

[3] http://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/using_xmpp